# Equality in distribution

Tags: self-study, distributions, normal-distribution

I have a problem at hand which involves showing equality of distribution and I have no idea how to proceed and what to show ultimately.

Let

$$\left(\matrix{U\\V}\right)\sim N_2\left(\left(\matrix{0\\0}\right),\left(\matrix{1& \rho\\\rho & 1}\right)\right) $$

Show that
$$\left(\matrix{U\\V}\right)\stackrel{d}{=}\left(\matrix{X\\\rho X +\sqrt{1-\rho^2}Y}\right)$$

where $X,Y\stackrel{iid}{\sim} N(0,1)$ and $\rho$ is the covariance of $U\&V$

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to show that the 2 sides of the equal sign have the same join distribution or join density.

You can start with

1/ Cumulative distribution:

$P(U<u, V<v)$ and $P(X<x, Z<z)$ with $Z = \rho X +...$

You need to show that those are equal given assumptions of U,V,X and Y

OR

2/ join density:

$f(u,v)$ and $f(x,z)$

You need to show that those are equal given assumptions of U,V,X and Y

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please up vote my question if you liked it.